# Run all coroutines class test fail

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was testing my presenter class and all test work. But when I tried to run my test class, all coroutines test fail.

I'm trying reset my dispatch and clean my scope.

private val dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

```
private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher)

@Before
fun setUp() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    products = ProductsMotherObject.createEmptyModel()
    getProductsUseCase = GetProductsUseCase(productsRepository)
    updateProductsUseCase = UpdateProductsUseCase(productsRepository)
    presenter = HomePresenter(view, getProductsUseCase, updateProductsUseCase, products)
}

@After
fun after() {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
    testScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()
}
```

and this is an example of my tests

```
@Test
fun `should configure recyclerview if response is success`() = testScope.runBlockingTest {
    //Given
    `when`(productsRepository.getProductsFromApi()).thenReturn(mutableMapOf())

    //when
    presenter.fetchProducts()

    //then
    verify(view).hideLoading()
    verify(view).setUpRecyclerView(products.values.toMutableList())
}
```

I have only single errors from my tests, but each test works when run single

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I found [this incredible post](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/).

What have I done:

I implemented my dispacher without constructor.

```
    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
```

You have to set on @Before function

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
}
```

And reset after test.

```
@After
fun after() {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
    testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
}
```

Finally each test that implements coroutines must launch on MainScope.

```
@Test
fun `should configure recyclerview if response is success`() = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
    MainScope().launch {
        //Given
        `when`(productsRepository.getProductsFromApi()).thenReturn(mutableMapOf())

        //when
        presenter.fetchProducts()

        //then
        verify(view).hideLoading()
        verify(view).setUpRecyclerView(products.values.toMutableList())
    }
}
```